# MvvmCross, platform-specific value converter not being invoked

Tags: android, data-binding, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross with Xamarin.Android.  I have the Visibility plugin installed.  In my Android application project, I have created an Android-specific visibility converter that supports the Invisible state (view not shown, but still taking up layout space):

```
public class VisibleOrInvisibleValueConverter
  : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
{
  public ViewStates Convert(bool value, Type targetType, CultureInfo cultureInfo, object parameter)
  {
    MvxTrace.Error("VisibleOrInvisibleValueConverter.Convert");
    return value ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
  }
}
```

In my .axml markup, I use this converter like this:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility Selected, Converter=VisibleOrInvisible, FallbackValue=0" />
```

Based on the documentation at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#referencing-value-converters-in-touch-and-droid, I believe that MvvmCross will automatically discover the existence of this value converter, since it is in my UI project.

At runtime, the bound value always takes on the fallback value, no matter what the value of Selected is.  Based on the documentation at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#referencing-value-converters-in-touch-and-droid, this means that either my binding source path is missing, or the value converter threw an exception.

Unfortunately, I think I can rule both of those out.  For the first possibility, I tried replacing my custom VisibleOrInvisible converter with the stock MvvmCross Visibility converter, and it worked fine.  (That is, the binding worked fine.  The stock Visibility converter doesn't support my desired behavior, though.)  Anyway, I think this shows that the source path (Selected) does exist.

For the second possibility, I've set a breakpoint in the Convert function of the VisibleOrInvisible converter, and it is never executed.  I also added an MvxTrace call in there, and I never see the trace message.

Although my converter is supposed to be automatically discovered, I have also tried explicitly adding my platform-specific assembly to the list of assemblies that implement value converters by overriding the ValueConverterAssemblies property getter in Setup.cs:

```
protected override List<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
{
  get
  {
    var toReturn = base.ValueConverterAssemblies;
    toReturn.Add(typeof (VisibleOrInvisibleValueConverter).Assembly);
    return toReturn;
  }
}
```

But this did not help.

I think that MvvmCross is discovering my converter OK.  If I intentionally refer to a non-existent converter in my .axml file, I see exception messages in the debug trace at runtime.  But when I specify my VisibleOrInvisible converter, these messages do not appear.

My working theory is that an exception is occurring in the process of invoking my converter, before the only line of code *in* the converter is executed.  But I don't know how to get to the bottom of that.  No exception messages appear in the debug trace.

Is there a simple step that I'm getting wrong?  I've studied the MvvmCross ValueConversion example pretty carefully, and I think I'm doing everything that example does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just taken the ValueConversion sample, upgraded the core csproj file to profile 158 and then inserted your value converter.

This converter was picked up fine - I could see it in the converter list using:

```
    protected override void InitializeLastChance ()
    {
        base.InitializeLastChance ();

        var registry = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxValueConverterLookup> ();
        var f = registry.Find("VisibleOrInvisible");
        Mvx.Trace ("Custom converter was found : {0}", f != null);
    }
```

However, when I tried to use it I saw binding errors about enum/bool/value type mapping... so I can see there is some problem...

---

After a little digging, it seems the reason for this problem was because your ValueConverter implements an unusual `public ViewStates Convert` method, instead of overriding the base class `Convert` method. To fix this I changed the converter to:

```
public class VisibleOrInvisibleValueConverter
    : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
{
    protected override ViewStates Convert (bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MvxTrace.Error("VisibleOrInvisibleValueConverter.Convert");
        return value ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
}
```

For more on authoring value converters using the `MvxValueConverter<...>` helpers, see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#using-the-mvxvalueconverter-helper (if there's some other sample or document somewhere that has the wrong sample, then "sorry" and please point it out to whoever owns it so they can fix it)

Further, you may find the source for `MvxValueConverter` helpful - it's hopefully pretty straight-forward to follow how it implements `IMvxValueConverter`: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Converters/MvxValueConverter.cs

---

With that problem solved, the next challenge presented by this question is how to use the `FallbackValue`. I've not fully analysed the trace I saw from this problem but I did experiment with a few other `FallbackValue` syntax examples - and these all seemed to work correctly:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility VisibleOrInvisible(ThisWillNotBeFound), FallbackValue=Visible"     />


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility VisibleOrInvisible(ThisWillNotBeFound), FallbackValue=Invisible"     />


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility VisibleOrInvisible(ThisWillNotBeFound, FallbackValue=true)" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    local:MvxBind="Visibility VisibleOrInvisible(ThisWillNotBeFound, FallbackValue=false)" />
```

I'm not sure if the numeric fallback value is working for this case currently - suspect it needs more investigation (will log as a potential issue).

Comment: Wow, it's amazing how one can be blind to things like that.  I must have block-copied my non-override, different-parameter-order Convert function from somewhere, but it wasn't from any of your examples.  That did fix my problem, thank you.

The integer fallback value in the .axml was left over from a previous experiment in which I was trying to use a non-enum type as the destination type of the converter.  I meant for it to be the Invisible value.